# Jetty Spring Web Services sqljdbc_auth.dll conflict

Tags: sql-server, web-services, hibernate, spring, jetty

We have created 2 web services from similar code bases that are using Spring and Hibernate and we are wanting to run them in a Jetty Server.  Each Web server can initliaze the wsdl just fine from Spring.  If I send a message to one web service that ends up connecting to a database it runs fine.  As soon as I call the second web service it tries to connect to the database but fails.  We are using hibernate and sql server's jdbc driver.  The failure occurs when the second web service tries to use the sqljdbc_auth.dll.  See below:

2011-09-22 10:28:41,873  WARNING [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.internals.AuthenticationJNI] - Failed
 to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll

Is there a file locking issue with the dll?  Where the first web service has a lock and the second one does not?

Answer (score 0):

Please copy `sqljdbc_auth.dll` file in to *jdk* bin folder, i.e. *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6_32\bin*.

Paste file in your server side where the JVM is running.

If consuming web services please apply the same in client side as well.